# ansible telnet without username and password

Tags: ansible, cisco

I have to make an ansible playbook that connects to a brand new cisco router via a telnet connection to a terminal concentrator on a specefic telnet port.

This is my playbook so far

```
---
- name: Telnet test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: telnet test
      telnet:
        host: 10.145.0.200
        port: 4009
        send_newline: yes
        prompts:
          - '[>|#]'
        command:
          - enable
          - term len 0
          - show ver
```

My issue is that when the connection is made the playbook just stay in the task without sending any command to the cisco router, how can i connect to a device without username and password?

i had to cancel the playbook since it will just stay in the task forever

```
ansible-playbook 2.9.13
  config file = /home/niclas/ansible/gc/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/niclas/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/niclas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) [GCC 9.3.0]
Using /home/niclas/ansible/gc/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /home/niclas/ansible/gc/inventory.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/niclas/ansible/gc/inventory.yml inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: testTelnet.yml ***********************************************************************************************
1 plays in testTelnet.yml

PLAY [Telnet test] *****************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [telnet test] *****************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/niclas/ansible/gc/testTelnet.yml:6
^C [ERROR]: User interrupted execution
```

Edit error:

```
❯ ansible-playbook testTelnet.yml -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.9.13
  config file = /home/niclas/ansible/gc/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/niclas/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/niclas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) [GCC 9.3.0]
Using /home/niclas/ansible/gc/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /home/niclas/ansible/gc/inventory.yml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/niclas/ansible/gc/inventory.yml inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: testTelnet.yml ***********************************************************************************************
1 plays in testTelnet.yml

PLAY [Telnet test] *****************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [telnet test] *****************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/niclas/ansible/gc/testTelnet.yml:6
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/niclas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 147, in run
    res = self._execute()
  File "/home/niclas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_executor.py", line 665, in _execute
    result = self._handler.run(task_vars=variables)
  File "/home/niclas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/telnet.py", line 59, in run
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host, port, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/telnetlib.py", line 218, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/telnetlib.py", line 235, in open
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.",
    "stdout": ""
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Please show a debug run of that taks (using `-vvv` on the playbook). You should also show an output of a manual telnet session to that device showing initial dialog, prompt, etc... Note: do not try to add this info in comments, edit your question.

Comment: i have edited the question. With the telnet port 4009 i am connecting to the console port on the cisco router.

Comment: I don't see your telnet session example. Since it probably hangs waiting for a prompt, it's going to be hard for anyone to answer without knowing what the exact dialog looks like...

Comment: i have tried to use wireshark doing the telnet session and my pc will recieve this prompt ">" but my script will never respond

Comment: Did you try with `prompts: [">"]` then ? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/netcommon/telnet_module.html#parameter-prompts

Comment: thank you very much, i have updated my question with an actual error i get when i changed the prompt setting to [">#"]

Answer (score 0):

I think the ansible's command interpreter can't understand the promt from the cisco. I think you should use cisco.ios plugin instead which is described here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_command_module.html

### UPDATE

Because the telnet task does not understand cisco.ios commands, then you should use another approach for connecting. Hope your cisco device support SSH, then you can make the connection.

In this case, I think your playbook should look like this:

```
ansible_connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
ansible_network_os: cisco.ios.ios
ansible_user: cisco
ansible_password: ciscopass
ansible_become: yes
ansible_become_method: enable
ansible_become_password: if_you_have_enable_password_define_it_here

---
- hosts: ansible.ini_defined_group_name_for_cisco_device
    tasks:
    - name: log into cisco device and init this commands
      cisco.ios.ios_command:
        commands:
          - show version
          - term len 0
```

Comment: i have changed my playbook to your sugestion, but now i get this error "Telnet requires a command to execute"

Comment: It seems using the cisco.ios module, it is impossible to use with telnet. I updated my answer, which will make an SSH connection for it.

Comment: i am not able to use SSH since i have to automate deployment of many cisco routers to a costumer, just by transfering a image file and a configuration to the router and then reload it. I can only use telnet to the console concentrator